# What's the disadvantage of this shuffle algorithm compare to other shuffle algorithm?

Tags: random, shuffle

What's the disadvantage of this shuffle algorithm compare to other shuffle algorithm? For example, Fisher–Yates.

Code source: http://www.vcskicks.com/randomize_array.php

```
private List<E> ShuffleList<E>(List<E> inputList)
{
 List<E> randomList = new List<E>();

 Random r = new Random();
 int randomIndex = 0;
 while (inputList.Count > 0)
 {
      randomIndex = r.Next(0, inputList.Count); //Choose a random object in the list
      randomList.Add(inputList[randomIndex]); //add it to the new, random list
      inputList.RemoveAt(randomIndex); //remove to avoid duplicates
 }

 return randomList; //return the new random list
}
```

By the way, is there a name for this algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm is good from the perspective of the generated list -- in fact, every possible permutation of the elements is equally likely to be returned.

The disadvantage is its complexity, it runs in `O(n^2)` time, because on every iteration either finding the element (if the list happens to be a linked list) or removing it from the list (if it happens to be an array list) will take linear time.